# React-native constructor and componentWillMount scope issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to display all items in my array monthDays with map.
The problem is that i need to execute some logic in a componetWillMount to creact the array by pushing items to it in a loop.
The alterations that i made in the componetWillMount are not afecting the array in the constructor.
Sorry if im not being clear, my english is not that good
Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Calendar extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
    this.monthDays = ['I want to put this array'];
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    let monthDays = ['in this scope'];
    let defineDays = Number(this.props.days);
    let daysCount = 1;
    let x = 0;

    while (monthDays.length < defineDays) {
      monthDays.push(daysCount);
      daysCount++;
      this.setState({ text : monthDays[x]});
      x++;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.monthDays.map(( teste, key ) => (
        <View key = { key }>
          <Text>{ teste }</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Ps: defineDays only received a prop with the number of days the month have

Comment: Why don't use just monthDays as part of state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  let monthDays = ['in this scope'];
  let defineDays = Number(this.props.days);
  let daysCount = 1;
  let x = 0;

  while (monthDays.length < defineDays) {
    monthDays.push(daysCount);
    daysCount++;
    this.setState({ text: monthDays[x] });
    x++;
  }

  // Assign the new values to your current array
  this.monthDays = monthDays;
}
```

If you are going to receive props new props over the time you need to do the same thing in `componentWillReceiveProps` if you want to maintain `this.monthDays` updated.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export default class Calendar extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
       super();
       this.mapFunction = this.mapFunction.bind(this);
    }
    function mapFunction() {
       var arr = []
       for(var dayscount=0; dayscount < this.props.days; dayscount++){
           arr.push(dayscount);
       }
       return arr.map((test, key) => {
            return (
              <View key = { key }>
                <Text>{ test }</Text>
              </View>
            )
       })
    }

    render(){
       return(
          <View>
            { this.mapFunction }
          </View>
       )
    }
}
```

Make sure you are setting `this.props.days` correctly and it's value is an integer.

Comment: That shouldn't include a semicolon. Anyway, you can try the other way round of creating a function by replacing mapFunction = () => { ...  } with function mapFunction() { ... } And then replace { this.mapFunction() } with { this.mapFunction } Also, you will have to bind this function inside constructor() like so: this.mapFunction = this.mapFunction.bind(this)

Comment: aprently {this.mapFunction();} wasent regognized as a function [heres a print](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DGDU1inzb83dgFGkf7h3aenLLBZXJfpY)